# The deletion of a file does not throw IOException if it is being read by inpustream

Tags: java

While reading from a file by `BufferedReader`, if I delete the file by `rm -rf` the `BufferedReader` terminates without `IOException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, expected behaviour. Deleting a file on Unix-like systems involves removing a link to the file's data location in the directory entry table. When there are no links to the file, and no file descriptors open to it, it's space will be reclaimed. As there is a file descriptor currently open (through your use of BufferedReader), it will remain open until the BufferedReader finishes. Although the file is open, it is not visible in the directory listing.